# Why am I getting empty Array outside of FOR loop in Typescript (Angular CLI)?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli

Before raising this question, I have gone through the similar issues raised, but no luck in fixing my issue. So I'm raising this question again to understand on why exactly this is happening.

I started creating one web application where in one of my page users can download data by just clicking the button provided. Everything worked fine till I started using FOR loop to get some additional data and adding it to new array. Here is my code for better explaination.

**employee-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestApiService } from "../shared/rest-api.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees-list',
  templateUrl: './employees-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesListComponent implements OnInit {

  term: string;
  Employee: any = [];
  assets: any = [];
  reportData: any = [];

  constructor(
    public restApi: RestApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadEmployees()
  }

  // Get employees list
  loadEmployees() {
    return this.restApi.getEmployees().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.Employee = data;
    })
  }

  //Download Employee report
  download() {
    let fileName = 'EmployeeReport.csv';
    let columnNames = ["Emp ID", "Employee ID", "First Name", "Last Name","Email","Department ID","Designation",
    "Emp Active","Inventory ID","Device Name","Device Type ID","Device Type Name","Serial No","Model","Processor",
    "RAm ID","HDD ID","OS ID","Warranty Date","Purchase Date","Description","Repair","Inv Active","RAM Size","HDD Size","OS Name","Asset Status"];
    let header = columnNames.join(',');
    let csv = header;
    csv += '\r\n';

    ####create an reportData array####
    //*******parent for loop**********
    for(let emp of this.Employee){
      this.restApi.getEmployeeAsset(emp.id).subscribe((data: {}) => {
        this.assets = data;
        if(this.assets.length !== 0){
          //*****child for loop****
          for(let asset of this.assets){
             this.reportData.push({"eid": emp.id,"employeeId":emp.employee_id,"firstName":emp.first_name,"lastName":emp.last_name,"email":emp.email,        "departmentId":emp.department_id,"designation":emp.designation,"eActive":emp.is_active,"invId":asset.id,"deviceName":asset.device_name,         "deviceTypeId":asset.device_type_id,"deviceTypeName":asset.device_type_name,"serialNo":asset.serial_no,"model":asset.model,"processor":asset.processor,          "ramId":asset.ram_id,"hddId":asset.hdd_id,"osId":asset.os_id,"warrantyDate":asset.warranty_date,"purchaseDate":asset.purchased_date,          "description":asset.description,"repair":asset.repair,"invActive":asset.is_active,"ramSize":asset.ram_size,"hddSize":asset.hdd_size,"osName":asset.os_name,"assetStatus":asset.asset_status})
          }
        }
        else {
          this.reportData.push({"eid": emp.id,"employeeId":emp.employee_id,"firstName":emp.first_name,"lastName":emp.last_name,"email":emp.email,
          "departmentId":emp.department_id,"designation":emp.designation,"eActive":emp.is_active})
        }

          console.log("Report Data is available here"+JSON.stringify(this.reportData))  
      })
      console.log("Report data is empty here"+JSON.stringify(this.reportData))

  }
    this.reportData.map(c => {csv += [c["eid"], c["employeeId"],c["firstName"],c["lastName"],c["email"],c["departmentId"],c["designation"],c["eActive"], c["invId"],c["deviceName"],c["deviceTypeId"],c["deviceTypeName"],c["serialNo"],c["model"],c["processor"],c["ramId"],  c["hddId"],c["osId"],c["warrantyDate"],c["purchaseDate"],c["description"],c["repair"],c["invActive"],c["ramSize"],c["hddSize"],c["osName"],c["assetStatus"]].join(',');
      csv += '\r\n';
    })

    var blob = new Blob([csv], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;" });

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    if (link.download !== undefined) {
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.setAttribute("href", url);
      link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
  }

}
```

Here in this code, under `download()` method, I'm creating an array `reportData` which later I'm converting it to csv format which can be downloaded.

But this particular array `reportData` is empty once we are out of `this.restApi.getEmployeeAsset(emp.id).subscribe` call with in the `parent for loop`. This seems to be weird for me and I'm really not understanding why this is happening.

I found this by logging results to the console at 2 different places with in the for loop. 
one is `console.log("Report Data is available here"+JSON.stringify(this.reportData))` with in the subscribe method of API call where I can see the `reportData` and another one is `console.log("Report data is empty here"+JSON.stringify(this.reportData))` where `reportData` is empty.

Can someone please explain what mistake I'm doing here and why exactly this is happening?

I don't have any errors showing and I was able to download the required file, but with empty data which has only Header column. :(

**Work around that currently I had in place**

I placed the `For loop logic` from `download()` to `loadEmployees()` which in turn is being called under `ngOnInIt()`. So the necessary data will loaded when component is invoked or executed. (But I know this is not an efficient way)

```
loadEmployees() {
    this.restApi.getEmployees().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.Employee = data;
      for(let emp of this.Employee){
        this.restApi.getEmployeeAsset(emp.id).subscribe((data: {}) => {
          this.assets = data;
          if(this.assets.length !== 0){
          for(let asset of this.assets){
            this.reportData.push({"eid": emp.id,"employeeId":emp.employee_id,"firstName":emp.first_name,"lastName":emp.last_name,"email":emp.email,
            "departmentId":emp.department_id,"designation":emp.designation,"eActive":emp.is_active,"invId":asset.id,"deviceName":asset.device_name,
            "deviceTypeId":asset.device_type_id,"deviceTypeName":asset.device_type_name,"serialNo":asset.serial_no,"model":asset.model,"processor":asset.processor,
            "ramId":asset.ram_id,"hddId":asset.hdd_id,"osId":asset.os_id,"warrantyDate":asset.warranty_date,"purchaseDate":asset.purchased_date,
            "description":asset.description,"repair":asset.repair,"invActive":asset.is_active,"ramSize":asset.ram_size,"hddSize":asset.hdd_size,
            "osName":asset.os_name,"assetStatus":asset.asset_status})
            }
          }
          else {
            this.reportData.push({"eid": emp.id,"employeeId":emp.employee_id,"firstName":emp.first_name,"lastName":emp.last_name,"email":emp.email,
            "departmentId":emp.department_id,"designation":emp.designation,"eActive":emp.is_active})
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

I know this approach is not that efficient, because the `reportData` array will be created at the backend irrespective of whether Download button is clicked or not. But Since I'm not getting how to handle this using `Promises` or to handle Asynchronous coding, I ended up doing this.

Comment: `this.restApi.getEmployeeAsset(emp.id)` this statement is executed asynchronously, so by the time you call `this.reportData.map` after the loop...the asyncs are still running hence no data pushed in...

Comment: @AshwynHorton I never expected this will cause an issue. New learning for me. Let me try other ways and get back to you.

Comment: sure man...check out Promises, lemme format this though and drop an answer if you dont mind

Comment: @AshwynHorton Thank you and that would be helpful for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing async code with synchronous code in a way that results in your data array not being populated with the results. The async code is still executing by the time `this.reportData.map()` is being called. Need to consider using some of the rxjs operators on your API request.

```
download() {
  ...csv setup here
  // Create an array of observables based on the Employee array
  forkJoin(this.Employee.map(emp => this.restApi.getEmployeeAsset(emp.id))
    // Pipe the Observables through the map operator to set up data
    .pipe(
      map(assets => {
        assets.forEach(
          if(assets.length !== 0){
            this.reportData.push(...the data you want)
          } else {
            this.reportData.push(...the other data you want)
          }
      })
    ).subscribe(() => {
      ...do what you need here with mapping over this.reportData to create your csv
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Nolan, I will try this approach and get back to you with results.

Comment: - Since I'm new to this approach, I tried to replicate your code (I mean syntax) but it is throwing error saying `map` after .pipe operator should be fixed and it is not recognized. Can you please explain how exactly this should be handled?

Error saying, Cannot find name 'map', do you mean Map?

Comment: Can you please help me in understanding this better on how to implement this approach? Meanwhile I did work around which I have placed in my actual post.